# LINQ to XML join with idref

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML structure like the following:

```
[...]
<Fruits>
   <Fruit>
      <Specification>id_1001_0</Specification> 
      <Weight>23</Weight>
   </Fruit>
</Fruits>
<FruitSpecification id="id_1001_0">
   <Type>Apple</Type>
</FruitSpecification>
[...]
```

I want to use Linq to XML to read this into (non-anonymous) objects.
Let´s say i have the following code:

```
var fruits = from xele in xDoc.Root.Element("Fruits").Elements("Fruit")
             select new Fruit()
             {
                Weight = xele.Element("Weight").Value
             }
```

How can i extend the query to join the correct `FruitSpecification` tag?
The goal would be to be able to write this:

```
var fruits = from xele in xDoc.Root.Element("Fruits").Elements("Fruit")
             //some join?
             select new Fruit()
             {
                Weight = xele.Element("Weight").Value,
                Type = xjoinedelement.Element("Type").Value
             }
```

I hope this is understandable, i made this "fruit" sample up, my actual XML is much more complicated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simple join will do the trick:

```
var fruits = 
    from f in xdoc.Root.Element("Fruits").Elements("Fruit")
    join fs in xdoc.Root.Elements("FruitSpecification")
         on (string)f.Element("Specification") equals (string)fs.Attribute("id")
    select new Fruit()
    {
         Weight = (int)f.Element("Weight"),
         Type = (string)fs.Element("Type")
    };
```

Fruit class definition:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think i missed the (string) part when i tried it a way like this

Comment: @Jobo welcome :) Btw it's better to use casting then accessing `Value` property (if node is missing casting will return default value, but accessing property will throw a NullReferenceException)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Fruit
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

string xml = @"
            <root>
                <Fruits>
                    <Fruit>
                        <Specification>id_1001_0</Specification> 
                        <Weight>23</Weight>
                    </Fruit>
                    <Fruit>
                        <Specification>id_1002_0</Specification> 
                        <Weight>25</Weight>
                    </Fruit>
                </Fruits>
                <FruitSpecification id='id_1001_0'>
                    <Type>Apple</Type>
                </FruitSpecification>
                <FruitSpecification id='id_1002_0'>
                    <Type>Orange</Type>
                </FruitSpecification>
            </root>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);

IEnumerable<XElement> xFruites = element.Descendants("Fruit");
IEnumerable<XElement> xFruitSpecifications = element.Descendants("FruitSpecification");
IEnumerable<Fruit> frits = xFruites.Join(
    xFruitSpecifications,
    f => f.Element("Specification").Value,
    s => s.Attribute("id").Value,
    (f, s) =>
    new Fruit
        {
            Type = s.Element("Type").Value,
            Weight = int.Parse(f.Element("Weight").Value)
        });
```

Comment: although this works, the answer from lazyberezovsky fits better for me, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jobo What do you mean by " better for me". Just interested.

Comment: With your solution i would end up with having a ton of `IEnumerable<T>`s outside my actual query. My actual XML has around 10 id-referenced tag types and with the accepted solution im able to write a sql-like query with nested queries which looks "prettier" and more understandable to me.

Comment: @Jobo `IEnumerable-s`used to simplify understanding. In OP you don't use `"sql-like"` query, thereby i use extensions method syntax as you. P.S. As you don't described full `XML` in some cases `lazyberezovsky's` solution won't be works. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: I prefer the query syntax, thats what i meant with "sql-like". your solution uses the method syntax. My question is written in query syntax. The query syntax will be much more readable, in my opinion, if you have lots of nested selects and joins and so on.